# Dependency Injection no funciona en Symfony

Tags: symfony, inyeccion-de-dependencias

He revisado varios enlaces [1](https://medium.com/@votanlean/symfony-parameters-and-environment-variables-ac916524ab49) [2](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) antes de preguntar.

Necesito que varias clases que se ejecutan en un comando de consola tengan acceso a Doctrine. Y como no es un controller entonces necesitaría hacerlo vía injecion de dependencias. Pero no funciona. Al ejecutar dice que no recibe ninguna variable, no se inyecta nada.

Así que la pregunta es ¿Que falta por hacer y que no explica ninguno de los enlaces indicados?

Mi services.yaml (no entero):

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true 
        autoconfigure: true

    App\Mario\MarioBundle\Core\Paradespues\Paradespues:
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

Y este el codigo de Paradespues (faltan lineas de use)

```
<?php
namespace App\Mario\MarioBundle\Core\Paradespues;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Paradespues
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->pocket=new Pocket();
        $this->em=$em;
    }
```

¿Que me puede faltar? En "arguments" he probado a poner "EntityManager", la clase entera con el namespace y otras variaciones. Y ni siquiera me daba error al poner nombres inventados. Y en el constructor tambien he probado a quitar "Interface". Y nada. No recibe nada.